Bash script not working when running in php page but works in terminal
Hey all I am trying to get a bash script to fire off when I visit my php page. I am using XAMPP that is hosting my php on my MacOS.
Here is my php code:
<?php
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    ob_end_flush();

    $cmd = "bash sysinfo1.sh";
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"), //stdin pipe will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"), //stdout pipe will write to
        2 => array("pipe", "w")  //stderr pipe will write to
    );
    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realPath('./'), array());

    if (is_resource($process)) {
        while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])){
            echo $s;
        }
    }

    echo ']';
?>

And this is the bash script code:
#!/bin/bash
system_profiler -json SPHardwareDataType SPSoftwareDataType SPNetworkDataType SPStorageDataType

When visiting the php page (192.168.1.15:87) it loads the page just fine but has no output on the page other than the "]". I changed the $pipes[1] to $pipes[2] and got the error:
sysinfo1.sh: line 4: system_profiler: command not found ]

I chmod 755 the bash script as well. And the .sh file is located in the same directory as the php file. The .sh script runs just fine in terminal (./sysinfo1.sh).
What could I be missing?

Try using the full path to the system_profiler and the shell script instead of just their names.

Happen to know what that path would be, @choroba?

type system_profiler should tell you.

Found it!
/usr/sbin/system_profiler -json SPHardwareDataType SPSoftwareDataType SPNetworkDataType SPStorageDataType
Thanks for the tip choroba
